# Преобразовать число в двоичное

Tags: javascript

Я использую функцию .toString(2), но при её использование пропадает первые нули. Что делать?

Comment: пример кода выложите

Comment: (12).toString(2) - результат должен быть 00001100, не мне даёт 1100, без нулей спереди

Comment: а сколько нулей та хочешь добавить?

Comment: мне надо добавить нулей, мне надо функция которая преобразовать любое число в двоичное, а ту которую. использую преобразовать число в двоичное, но убирает нуль спереди

Comment: лидирующие нули не имеют значения, поэтому их опускают. Если тебе нужны лидирующие нули ты должен их добавить сам, сколько тебе нужно. Плюс непонятно, почему ты хочешь чтобы было именно `00001100`, а не `0000000000001100` или `000000000000000000001100`?

Comment: @Grundy а лучше `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000110`  :-)

Comment: @СергейМишин, не, если считать, что на целые числа в js выделено 53 бита, то 53 знака должно быть: `00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001100`